# How to get value from another method before main activity is processed?

Tags: java, android, xml, methods, settext

I want the phonenumber to be loaded into string xx"...how is it possible??How to share data between methods?? I have tried to make the method public but that wont help....I know the activity starts from main activity...so how is it possible to get data from another method and then process main activity?

```
public class MsgcontactActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;
    public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) 
    {  
        Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
        startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);  
    }

    EditText phoneTxt;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String xx=phoneTxt.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), xx,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    {  
         String phone="";
         Cursor contacts=null;
         try
         {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            {  
                switch (requestCode) 
                {  
                    case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:  
                        Uri result = data.getData();
                        String id = result.getLastPathSegment(); 
                        contacts=getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },  null);
                        int phoneIdx = contacts.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA); 
                        if (contacts.moveToFirst()) 
                        {
                           phone = contacts.getString(phoneIdx);  
                           EditText phoneTxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneno);
                           phoneTxt.setText(phone);
                        } 
                        else 
                        {  
                           Toast.makeText(this, "error", 100).show();
                        }  
                        break;  
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Warning: activity result not ok",50).show();
                }  
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {  
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 50).show();  
            } 
            finally 
            {  
                if (contacts != null) 
                {  
                    contacts.close();  
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

XML Code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/phoneno"  
        android:inputType="text|phone"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Contacts"  
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <Button  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/Contacts"  
        android:text="Contacts"  
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:onClick="doLaunchContactPicker"/>
    <TextView 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/phoneno" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Next Try**

```
public class MsgcontactActivity extends Activity {

private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;
public void doLaunchContactPicker(View view) 
    {  
        Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Contacts.CONTENT_URI);  
        startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);  

    }

EditText phoneTxt;
        Button b;
TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
                b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doLaunchContactPicker(v);

            }
        });



        String xx=phoneTxt.getText().toString();
        tv.setText(xx);
}


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
        {  
             String phone="";
             Cursor contacts=null;
             try
             {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
                {  
                    switch (requestCode) 
                    {  
                    case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:  

                     Uri result = data.getData();

                     String id = result.getLastPathSegment(); 

                     contacts=getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },  null);

                     int phoneIdx = contacts.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA); 
                     if (contacts.moveToFirst()) 
                     {

                           phone = contacts.getString(phoneIdx);  

                           EditText phoneTxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                           phoneTxt.setText(phone);     

                        } 
                     else 
                     {  
                      Toast.makeText(this, "error", 100).show();
                        }  
                     break;  
                    }  

                } 
                else 
                {  

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Warning: activity result not ok",50).show();  

                }  
            }
             catch (Exception e) 
             {  
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 50).show();  
                } 
             finally 
             {  
                if (contacts != null) 
                {  
                    contacts.close();  
                }
             }
    }
    }

}
```

HTML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1" android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"></Button>
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this `doLaunchContactPicker()` method after `setContentView(R.layout.main);` in onCreate() method and if you don't use view in `doLaunchContactPicker()` method then don't pass `View` as a parameter in method and add this line `Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Contacts);` after `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20027/discussion-between-zyonneo-and-igp)

Comment: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS...Just added this line in Manifest file...before <application..</application>

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your `doLaunchContactPicker` method from `onCreate`, right after `setContentView`

Comment: Actually when i click the "contacts button"... contact list should come..when i click the on the contact...the number should be displayed in edittext and textview....

Comment: I'm confused, you don't reference a button anywhere in the code above.